# sqlMessage : "Column 'name' cannot be null" reactjs + expressjs + axios

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to get infomarion from the FORM and want to submit it to mysql db using the POST api. But getting issue :

`sqlMessage : column 'name' cannot be null`

my sql output from console is:

```
code: "ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR"
errno: 1048
sql: "INSERT INTO students (`name`, `course`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)"
sqlMessage: "Column 'name' cannot be null"
sqlState: "23000"
```

My form.js code is written down below.
I am able to get the data from api but not able to insert data through api.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Form() {

const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    course: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
})

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/`)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
  return (
    <form className='container mt-5' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h3 className='heading my-3'>Submit Form</h3>
    <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" name="name" required placeholder='Shubham' 
        onChange={e => setValues({...values,name: e.target.value})}/>
    </div>
    <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="course" className="form-label">Course:</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="course" name="course" required placeholder='BCA'
        onChange={e => setValues({...values,course: e.target.value})}/>
    </div>
    <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" name="email" required placeholder='shubham@dev.com'
        onChange={e => setValues({...values,email: e.target.value})}/>
    </div>
    <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="phone" className="form-label">Phone:</label>
        <input type="tel" className="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required placeholder='+91 828401-4400' pattern="[0-9]{10}"
        onChange={e => setValues({...values,phone: e.target.value})}/>
        <small className="text-muted">Please enter a 10-digit phone number.</small>
    </div>
    <div className="mb-3">
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success mx-2">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" className="btn btn-danger mx-2">Reset Form</button>
    </div>
</form>
  )
}

export default Form
```

also my server.js file is:

```
import express from 'express';
import mysql from 'mysql2';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "react"
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM students";
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return res.json({ Message: "Error inside server" });
        return res.json(result);
    });
});


app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const sql = "INSERT INTO students (`name`, `course`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES (?)";
    const values = [
        req.body.name,
        req.body.course,
        req.body.email,
        req.body.phone
    ]
    db.query(sql, [values], (err,result) => {
        if(err) return res.json(err)
        return res.json(result);
    })
})




app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("Listening");
});
```

i tried ChatGPT, didn't help.
I am expecting that the issue should be resolved.

Comment: You are passing null values to all fields according to the  error message, so you need to check in your js code what is sent to the server and what is received. No genAI model can replace some old-fashioned debugging.

Comment: i wrote the code above, please check it. and tell me how can I fix it.

Comment: Why don't you debug your code and see where things go south?

Comment: because i am a beginner and i am just starting with react

Comment: In this case it is even more important for you to learn how debug your code. Check if react sends the correct data, check if node.js, etc.